# Can't find correct codec for reading csv

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8, ascii, codec

I am reading a csv file, this come for some traces that are from a network protocol, hexa characters and normal mixed.
I am trying to read a .csv, and I have tried several encodings: utf-8, cp1252, latin1...

For **latin1**:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0' in position 51: ordinal not in range(128)

For **utf-8**:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 51: invalid start byte

For **cp1252**:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0' in position 51: ordinal not in range(128)

The code used is:

```
df=pd.read_csv(file,sep='`',error_bad_lines=False,encoding='cp1252',names=colnames,quotechar='"')
```

I am no big expert in encoding(s), but I would like to know how to solve it.

Find out the current encoding of the csv file i am reading?

Is there a very permissive codec that takes pretty much everything?

Thanks.

Comment: What's inside your csv ?

Comment: For utf-8 you get an expected `UnicodeDecodeError` in `read_csv` because it contains a non utf-8 character. For Latin1 and cp1252 you get a `UnicodeEncodeError` (note **Encode** instead of **Decode**) probably in a different instruction. I need the full stacktraces and the relevant code to be able to help you.

Comment: Only the writer knows the character encoding. Ask, read documentation, applicable standards or watch for ways in which it is communicated (e.g., HTTP response header Content-Type.) Or—if the source supports it—use a format that doesn't suffer from this problem, such as .ods or .xlsx.

Comment: with `cp1252` you shouldn't get error `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0'`. You can get it only with `ascii`. Using `b'\xb0'.decode('cp1252')` I see it can be `°` (degree sign)

Comment: What @furas says is correct about both latin1 and cp1252. Latin1 is your answer (amongst the dozens of character encodings that use all 256 bytes values in any order). It seems a bad test led to the question.

Comment: The error message you say you get from `latin-1` is not actually from that codec. It says it can't encode the character into `ascii` - probably because you tried to print it to an ASCII-only terminal after successfully reading it, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

CSV is a text format; it's not really suitable for storing arbitrary blobs of binary data.

To solve your immediate problem, you can specify `´latin-1'` as the encoding. This codec has the unique feature that each single-byte character corresponds to exactly the same Unicode code point.

Beware, though, that this is somewhat likely to produce various kinds of [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) if you are not careful. You should probably pull out any binary data, then decode the remaining fields to proper Unicode as soon as possible. Here's a simple pure Python snippet for UTF-8 with one field containing binary.

```
with open(filename, encoding='latin-1') as input:
    reader = csv.reader(input)
    for row in reader:
        binary = row[42].encode('latin-1')
        newrow = []
        for field in row:
            newrow.append(field.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8'))
        newrow[42] = binary
        # newrow is now decoded UTF-8 except field 42 which is a bytes object
```

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Pandas to provide a `pd` solution but it should not be hard to derive one from this, I hope.

Answer (score -1):

First find out the **type of encoding** then use it for reading

To find encoding type:

**Method:1** You can just open the file using notepad and then goto File -> Save As. Next to the Save button there will be an encoding drop down and the file's current encoding will be selected there.
**Method:2** In Linux systems, you can use file command. It will give the correct encoding

```
    > file sub01.csv
```

> sub01.csv: ASCII text

Comment: Please remove that non answer. It could at most be a comment (I know you currently have not enough rep.). And anyway it is wrong because `Latin1` is just an alias for `iso-8859-1`.

Comment: `file` doesn't give the "correct" encoding. It gives one of many possible encodings based on the sample. That said, it is close to what's being asked for: "a permissive" encoding. `file`'s answer would be "permissive" for that sample.

Answer (score -1):

for reading a csv file

```
import csv
def unicode_csv_reader(utf8_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
   csv_reader = csv.reader(utf8_data, dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
   for row in csv_reader:
      yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]
   filename = 'da.csv'
   reader = unicode_csv_reader(open(filename))
   for field1, field2, field3 in reader:
       print field1, field2, field3
```